# What test should be used to find if a COVID-19 has had significant effect on monthly sales?

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance

I have 10 years of monthly Drink sales (in litres per capita). Sales of some drink categories dropped sharply in April and May 2020 when COVID-19 restrictions were imposed by government (eg. “Stay home”). What test should I perform to examine whether the drop in sales is statistically significant?

Comment: What is the relevance of "significant"?  We are trying to [get away from significance](https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00031305.2016.1154108).  But directly to your point since you are not attempting to draw inference to another company or another time era, you don't need inference.  You can just be descriptive, with the addition of some measure of precision.

Comment: Welcome to CV! You can maybe look into using an intervention. Probably an abrupt temporary intervention. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/466066/284660) is a link to an answer I gave to someone that is pretty similar to what you are asking. @Bob

Comment: @FrankHarrell I can imagine the following question from a drinks supplier *"Descriptive: hey! my sales have dropped, we did something wrong. We need to react." "Reflective: maybe it is just random variation and not significant? We do not need to be worried about the change, at least not about the systematic part, and June and July will be good again."*

Comment: I see too many descriptive statistics in the news, focussing on tiny single changes without taking regard to natural fluctuations.  We need to get away from descriptive statistics. (Note: I am posing this as a devil's advocate, I am actually a fan of descriptive statistics, I am only worried about the abuse of descriptive statistics and am looking for a grayish area, and the point where it gets tricky).

Comment: Indeed we need something like descriptive *and* significant.  "You can just be descriptive, with the addition of some measure of precision." The part behind the comma is very important.